# Can't install MySQL client libraries on Gentoo

Tags: mysql, gentoo, emerge

I'm new in Gentoo. I'm trying get the mysql2 gem installed. But it's stuck. I found out that I need MySQL client libraries. I tried:

```
emerge dev-db/mysql:minimal

 * IMPORTANT: 2 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news to read news items.

 * IMPORTANT: config file '/etc/portage/package.keywords' needs updating.
 * See the CONFIGURATION FILES section of the emerge
 * man page to learn how to update config files.
Calculating dependencies... done!

emerge: there are no ebuilds to satisfy "dev-db/mysql:minimal".
```

And it is not installing. What do I need to do?

Comment: Try using the `minimal` USE Flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gems are usually not installed through portage. To install a Ruby gem, make sure `rubygems` is merged and then run `gem20 install <gem>` or `gem21 install <gem>` depending on your system.

Edit: since `emerge --search mysql-minimal` returns nothing, you know it isn't in the portage tree and can't be installed with emerge. Running `gem search mysql2` shows that the library can be installed with `gem install mysql2`.